# L1 Cach hits/misses to L2 Cash hits/misses

Tags: memory, arm, cpu-cache

I have a very basic Q but could not find an answer to it.
I'm using ARM DS-5 to capture stream line activities on MY BeagleBone board with Arm Cortex A8 processor.

I need the following L1 Cash hits and Misses, L2 hits/Misses and total memory access time.

I know the following "Correct me if I was wrong":
L1 misses = L2 hits + L2 misses
L1 hits = instructions - (L2 hits + L2 misses)

I can not apply this information to get l1 hits.
in the picture you will find l2 misses, l2 hits, no of instructions, and Data Access.

Data Access is defined as Memory read and write operation that causes a cash access to at least the level of data or unified cash closest to the processor.

[image]

These are the allowed counters in ARM DS-5
[image]
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to configure Streamline to monitor some of the more specific implementation-defined [performance events](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0344k/Bgbighbf.html) (0x40+), assuming that what it's showing there are the more generic 0x03 and 0x04?

Comment: I'm not very good at this but I added a picture of the allowed ounters on Arm for l1 cache. Thank you!